# Simple server test for node.js not working, no output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to node.js and **I am wondering the best way to test the following type of code in general**. Right now I am doing it all as one file in a netbeans node.js project. I am getting no output, the output should be "HELLO SERVER".

it usually compiles with no errors, but there is no output, other times it says

*"throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000"*

I already know what this rejection means and I think it is just doing that when I click run twice because then the port is occupied by the first run.

I have already tried on multiple ports, it works but with no output...

Should I be testing this some other way? Why is there no output? Output should be "HELLO SERVER" Thank you.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    request.on("data", function (chunk) {
        response.write(chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
    });
    request.on("end", function () {
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(8000);

var http = require("http");
var request = http.request({
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 8000,
    method: "POST"
}, function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
        process.stdout.write(chunk.toString());
    });
});
request.end("Hello Server");
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your port `8000` is already in use by another process. That process is **probably an older instance of your server still running** (not properly exited) that's still taking the port.

Try looking for the process using port `8000` and kill it

## On Linux

```
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

## On Windows

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8000
// Find the value of the PID (last column to the right)
taskkill /PID {pid_value} /F
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and the server starts up perfectly fine. The `"throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000"` means that the port you're starting the server on already has a server or another process running on it. Change the port number or stop the service

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  });
  request.on("data", function(chunk) {
    response.write(chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
  });
  request.on("end", function() {
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(3000);

var http = require("http");
var request = http.request({
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  method: "POST"
}, function(response) {
  response.on("data", function(chunk) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk.toString());
  });
});
request.end("Hello Server");
```

Comment: On the code you posted it is listening on a different port than it is requesting from, is that correct? I already looked up what the rejection means, sometimes it is running without that rejection but just with no output showing as it is doing now. I also switched the port to 0 which makes it look for any open port and it displays no output text....This question isn't just asking what that rejection means, it is asking the best way to test something like this in general and why is there no output...

Comment: @evanr123 thanks, missed that. And if that's your question you should edit it or re ask it to specify that you understand the error and want to know how to test it. Try maybe restarting your machine or clearing all ports from the terminal and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I will try restarting. So when you ran it you got the output to be "HELLO SERVER" ? or did it just start up with no output....

Comment: Yes, I got the output `HELLO SERVER` and everything worked as expected. Your code is fine the port is just in use by another process.

Comment: Just want to say that if you're still getting an issue after restart and youre trying ports like 8001, 8002 and other clearly unused ports than it is probably not an issue with node or your code. Maybe a networking issue? Ports are in use by your router?

Comment: But I usually am not getting any rejection, there is just no output....

Comment: use the command line to check what processes are running on the port when you start the server. Also just making sure you're running `node server.js` to start the server (with server.js being your js file).

Comment: The output in netbeans is just saying: ""/bin/bash" "-lc" "\"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/evanredmond/NetBeansProjects/NodeJsA/main.js\"""

Comment: Also, I havn't been able to run any javascript node.js files from the command prompt, it always says: "Error: Cannot find module '/Users/evanredmond/main.js'" with main.js being the file holding the code of this question....

Comment: NEVERMIND IT WORKS. Silly me, I had to click "STOP", when it stops running it displays that output, not while its running, hahaha. Thank you though, also any quick tips about the previous command line comment is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Glad you got it working! Check @molomk answer for how to kill ports. As for how to check them, it depends on your machine and can be found with a quick Google search (sorry I'm on mobile, not near a pc and dont remeber them off the top of my head)